# How to start writing service in java ee

Tags: java, json

I wanted to start writing my own service, which will gives iOS- app json and receive the same json, but I don't know from what I should start. Could you tall me some tutorial, and example?
Thank you

Comment: Look for JAX-RS tutorials

Comment: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028925.do ... http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529260.do

Comment: I would start at a more basic level like jetty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start with figure out how web services work.

I can recommend you REST approach. It is easy to set up and maintain. 
[Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html) you can find a good tutorial and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepu.html) there is something useful from Oracle.

Comment: Thank you. this tutorial helps me.